# Latin for "To become God"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

"To Become God"

It is a simple and asinine request, but google translate is apparently notoriously untrustworthy.

Anyone with real knowledge and a quick translation to Latin would make my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Well, that is easy, because we have the famous example of [Emperor Vespasian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vespasian) (9-79), who is often said to have uttered on his deathbed: "Woe me, I am becoming a god" (or something to that effect). In fact this anecdote is relayed by Suetonius in his biography of Vespasian, and it turns out it was not on the deathbed but at the first onset of illness. But he said it, and [there it is in chapter 23](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/suetonius/suet.vesp.html#23) in plain Latin:

> Ac ne in metu quidem ac periculo mortis extremo abstinuit iocis. [...] prima quoque morbi accessione: **Vae,** inquit, **puto, deus fio.**
>
> *And not even in fear and utter danger of death did he refrain from jokes. [...] Also, on the first onset of illness, he said: Woe, I think I'm becoming a god.*

And there you have it: "to become God" is **Deum fieri**.

Comment: He used Deus as nominative so maybe Deus/Dea fieri, methinks.

Comment: @Jacqueline: The use of nominative vs. accusative depends completely on the grammatical context. "Cupio deus/dea fieri" = "I desire to become (a) god", " "Cupio te deum/deam fieri", "I desire for you to become (a) god". See https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/16250/9

Comment: The *real* question is, what kind of grammar is *puto, deus fio*, Mister Vespasian??

Comment: @Jacqueline like Asteroides said, it depends on context; I chose the accusative because that's what you can use when talking about "becoming God" abstractively, e.g. *haud facile est deum fieri*.

Comment: Mister Vespasian's grammar is the canonical context where *deus* works, namely when this is the subject of the main clause. *putō* is interjectional here and doesn't govern, just like in English "I guess, I think". When an actual object clause is present, the nominative can only appear with certain experiential verbs when it's raised out of the object-clause to become the subject of the main clause in the first person singular, that is *ego*: *ego volō [mē deum fierī] > ego deus fierī volō.* See [the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_(linguistics)) for English examples.

Comment: Properly informative and specifically helpful, thanks everyone!

Comment: You have the same phrase in Seneca's *Apocolocyntosis*:  *"Olim" inquit "magna res erat deum fieri."*

Comment: To correct my previous comment, the *deus* works just as well in 2nd and 3d p. singular, and *dī/diī/deī* in the plural. What I needed to say was that the subject of the main verb must be the same as the verb of the acc.-inf. clause (*ego mē, tū tē, ille sē deum > ego, tū, ille deus*).

Answer (score 1):

The Romans believed that their emperors were gods, or at least became gods when they died. Vespasian’s “deus fio” is just a playful manner of saying “I am about to die”. In a Christian, or other monotheistic, context “deus fio” could mean “I am becoming God” in the sense of merging into the essence of the one God, if this is really what you want to say.

Comment: Must be intended to be a comment on the other answer...